# Como deletar não só tabelas mas um banco de dados no SQLite

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Gostaria de deletar não só uma tabelas mas o banco como um todo no SQLite. Pesquisando, me falaram de um método  `Context.deleteDatabase()`, mas não consigo usar, se tento chamar em um método, diz que ele não é estático para que seja usado numa classe estática, e eu não sei como instanciar um objeto "context" para usar essa função.

Está é minha classe Helper:

```
public class bdHelperUser extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String NOME_BD = "user.db";
    private static final int VERSAO_BD = 1;

    public bdHelperUser(Context ctx){
        super(ctx, NOME_BD, null, VERSAO_BD);//o terceiro item é um cursor factor (não obrigatório)
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlite) {
        //tabela principal de dados dos usuários
        String sql = "create table if not exists usuario (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                "nome text not null, endereco text not null, senha text not null, " +
                "mail text not null, cpf text not null, telefone text not null, " +
                "sexo text not null, dt_nascimento text not null, auto_login integer, " +
                "pin number(4), foto blob, apelido text);";

        sqlite.execSQL(sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //a cada versão nova do banco o script de mudança deve ser inserido


    }
}
```

Este é o método que quero deletar tudo até o banco:

```
public void deletarConta(View v) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.deletar_conta_titulo));

        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.del);

        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.deletar_conta_confima));

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.confirma, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
               String resposta =  crud.deletarUsuario(,"user.db");//aqui ocorre o erro
               exibirMsg(resposta);
                finish();
                login();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancela, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

            }
        });

        alerta = builder.create();

        alerta.show();
    }
```

E este é o método que deleta dados no banco:

```
public String deletarUsuario(Context ctx, String strg){

        try {
            sqLite = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            sqLite.delete("usuario", null, null);
            //sqLite.deleteDatabase(file);
            //sqLite.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS visitas");
            sqLite.close();
            ctx.deleteDatabase(strg);//aqui não consigo chamar esse método na activity pois não sei como criar um objeto Context pra passar como parâmetro e nem posso chamar esse método diretamente na classe

            return "Deletado com sucesso";
        }catch (SQLException erro){
           erro.getMessage();
            return "erro ao deletar";
        }
    }
```

Alguém pode me ajudar lançando um exemplo de como fazer isso via API, eu sei que se eu excluir o APP e reinstalar funciona mas queria saber fazer programaticmente.

Comment: Para apagar o banco de dados, você precisa também passar a extensão do banco. Exemplo: `ctx.deleteDatabase("databasename.db");`

Comment: esse "ctx".deleteDatabase... é um contexto certo? Como crio a instancia desse contexto para usar o método da classe Contexte (deleteDatabase)???

Comment: Quando você for usar o método `deletarUsuario`, você obviamente dependendo da `activity` que você estiver, deveria ser algo como `deletarUsuario(this, "databasename.db")`

Comment: tentei usar getBaseContext mas não funcionou, vou tentar como você diz. Obrigado!

Comment: Se você estiver fazendo isso em um `fragment`, ai você em vez de usar `this`, coloca `getActivity()`. Assim: `deletarUsuario(getActivity(), "databasename.db")`

Comment: Não é um Fragment mas foi bom saber, assim que testar aviso aqui se deu certo obrigado!

Comment: @AdsonLucasSilvadeFarias A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isto deva servir:

```
sqlite.deleteDatabase("nome do banco");
```

Ou isto:

```
ctx.deleteDatabase("nome do banco");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/SqliteDelete.java).

Comment: Acredito sim que o ctx.deleteDatabase("nome do banco"); resolva meu problema mas não sei como chamar este método na classe. Você tem algum exemplo de como usar? Como pego uma instância de Context no android studio?

Comment: Depende de como quer usar. Classes devem ser construídas de acordo com a necessidade. Precisa ver como e porque deseja apagar o banco de dados todos e prover o recurso necessário para ser consumido de acordo com a necessidade.

Comment: Estou construindo um app para servir de base de estudos na programação mobile (android), criei uma dela para deletar a conta do usuário, e quando deleto so a tabela fico impossibilitado de criar novamente um usuario a não ser que eu delete todo o app e posteriormente instale de novo, em meio a uns testes que fiz descobri q se eu mudar o nome do banco consigo criar um novo usuário sem precisar deletar o app, ai me veio a ideia q era preciso deletar todo o banco n so a tabela para poder recriar e cadastrar um novo usuário.

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas pra mim isso é gambiarra, acho melhor procurar um solução melhor para a arquitetura.

Comment: hummm, não sei se é um bug do sistema mas eu deleto a tabela usuário e quando tento cadastrar um novo usuário não consigo minha classe Helper aparentemente está ok. Mas obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Sim, é possível que seja um *bug* do seu sistema.